# XBAP childWindow control available similar to Silverlight 3 ChildWindow?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, xbap, silverlight-toolkit

The Silverlight 3 toolkit has a **ChildWindow** control for model popup like functionality.  This is great.  Anyone aware of a similar control that can be utilized via XBAP?

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%204&referringTitle=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203

The assumption is maybe someone ported the functionality back to WCF/XBAP?

Trying to find a solution without going to 3rd party purchased controls (against current company policy).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know that you'll get this to work without FullTrust (FullTrust XBAPs are a PITA until .NET 4). [Here's](http://www.julmar.com/blog/mark/PermaLink,guid,725cf1d9-3dc7-48f1-89f0-da8e3f3cfccb.aspx) a psuedo-workaround though- not as nice as SL ChildWindow, but it gets you basic popup functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In theory couldn't you rebuild the ChildWindow source and massage it a little to work on WPF? Most of the controls are WPF compatible, so it would make sense to build ChildWindow for XBAPs.